# Specifying dtype float32 with pandas.read_csv on pandas 0.10.1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm attempting to read a simple space-separated file with pandas `read_csv` method.  However, pandas doesn't seem to be obeying my `dtype` argument.  Maybe I'm incorrectly specifying it?

I've distilled down my somewhat complicated call to `read_csv` to this simple test case.  I'm actually using the `converters` argument in my 'real' scenario but I removed this for simplicity.

Below is my ipython session:

```
>>> cat test.out
a b
0.76398 0.81394
0.32136 0.91063
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy
>>> x = pandas.read_csv('test.out', dtype={'a': numpy.float32}, delim_whitespace=True)
>>> x
         a        b
0  0.76398  0.81394
1  0.32136  0.91063
>>> x.a.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I've also tried this using this with a `dtype` of `numpy.int32` or `numpy.int64`.  These choices result in an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I'm assuming the `AttributeError` is because pandas will not automatically try to convert/truncate the float values into an integer?

I'm running on a 32-bit machine with a 32-bit version of Python.

```
>>> !uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 13:25:36 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'ELF')
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.10.1'
```

Comment: I think this looks similar to [this issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2570)...

Comment: @AndyHayden I think you're right.  The `AttributeError` issue is exactly what the github issue is mentioning.  However, in my other scenario the values are floats but pandas doesn't obey the `dtype` argument when I try to use a float32 instead of a float64, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

0.10.1 doesn't really support float32 very much

see this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#dtype-specification

you can do this in 0.11 like this:

```
# dont' use dtype converters explicity for the columns you care about
# they will be converted to float64 if possible, or object if they cannot
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv'.....)

#### this is optional and related to the issue you posted ####
# force anything that is not a numeric to nan
# columns are the list of columns that you are interesetd in
df[columns] = df[columns].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)


    # astype
    df[columns] = df[columns].astype('float32')

see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#object-conversion

Its not as efficient as doing it directly in read_csv (but that requires
 some low-level changes)
```

I have confirmed that with 0.11-dev, this DOES work (on 32-bit and 64-bit, results are the same)

```
In [5]: x = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data), dtype={'a': np.float32}, delim_whitespace=True)

In [6]: x
Out[6]: 
         a        b
0  0.76398  0.81394
1  0.32136  0.91063

In [7]: x.dtypes
Out[7]: 
a    float32
b    float64
dtype: object

In [8]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.11.0.dev-385ff82'

In [9]: quit()
vagrant@precise32:~/pandas$ uname -a
Linux precise32 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Would `astype` or `convert_objects` be the preferred way to do this?

Comment: if u need a specif dtype then use astype, convert_objects is more meant for converting from object dtypes (and is not as necessary as was in prior versions)

Comment: So is this considered a bug in pandas?  It seems a bit deceiving that I can pass in a `dtype` and not get what I asked for or an error, etc.

Comment: see my answer, prob a bug in 0.10.1

Comment: +1 for `.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`, solved my problem of having a dataframe of mixed dtypes and wanting some of them to be resolved as floats.

Comment: FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric. However, If I try that: df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.to_numeric) then I get: ValueError: Unable to parse string. Anyone know how to implement the "to_numeric" in this case?

Answer (score 7):

```
In [22]: df.a.dtype = pd.np.float32

In [23]: df.a.dtype
Out[23]: dtype('float32')
```

the above works fine for me under pandas 0.10.1

Comment: fyi, this is inplace (which is implicit), and is not safe for non-float data

Comment: @Jeff Yes, this is an inplace cast and not safe for non-float values

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('sample.out', converters={'a':lambda x: pd.np.float32(x)}, delim_whitespace=True)` also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I like that this is inplace so it could be a bit better on memory and speed.  However, `convert_objects` will set NaN's if you use the `convert_numeric=True` argument.  This approach might raise some exceptions or something if the conversion can't be done.  However, I haven't looked into the details of this too much.

Comment: that's the point of convert_numeric=True, to remove 'nuisance' values from an otherwise numeric column