# Precision lost while using read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, floating-accuracy

I have files of the below format in a text file which I am trying to read into a pandas dataframe.

```
895|2015-4-23|19|10000|LA|0.4677978806|0.4773469340|0.4089938425|0.8224291972|0.8652525793|0.6829942860|0.5139162227|
```

As you can see there are **10** integers after the floating point in the input file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('mockup.txt',header=None,delimiter='|')
```

When I try to read it into dataframe, I am not getting the last 4 integers

```
df[5].head()

0    0.467798
1    0.258165
2    0.860384
3    0.803388
4    0.249820
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```

How can I get the complete precision as present in the input file? I have some matrix operations that needs to be performed so i cannot cast it as string.

I figured out that I have to do something about `dtype` but I am not sure where I should use it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is only display problem, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html?highlight=precision#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment):

```
#temporaly set display precision
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 10):
    print df

     0          1   2      3   4             5            6             7   \
0  895  2015-4-23  19  10000  LA  0.4677978806  0.477346934  0.4089938425   

             8             9            10            11  12  
0  0.8224291972  0.8652525793  0.682994286  0.5139162227 NaN
```

EDIT: (Thank you [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909368/precision-lost-while-using-read-csv-in-pandas/36909497?noredirect=1#comment61383096_36909497)):

> Pandas uses a dedicated decimal-to-binary converter that sacrifices perfect accuracy for the sake of speed. Passing `float_precision='round_trip'` to read_csv fixes this. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-method-for-floating-point-conversion) for more.

Comment: Thanks. Had one other rookie question. Is there any recommendation in general for faster loading into data frame while using read_csv() when data is mostly floating point values.

Comment: I think you can try set `dtypes`, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15210962/2901002).

Comment: It may be worth noting that this isn't *purely* a display problem, in the sense that if you use Pandas to write out a dataframe to a CSV file and then read it back in again, you can end up with small floating-point errors in the result: Pandas uses a dedicated decimal-to-binary converter that sacrifices perfect accuracy for the sake of speed. Passing `float_precision='round_trip'` to `read_csv` fixes this. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-method-for-floating-point-conversion) for more.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Thank you very much for comment, I add it to answer.

Comment: @MarkDickinson my notebook kernel dies once I set float_precision='round_trip'

Comment: This solves my issue! For some reason `float_precision=high` doesn't work but `float_precision=round_trip` works

Comment: @cozyss I also see that was the *only* way to fix the output as well, using Pandas v1.3.4.  But my saying that is somewhat of a deceit, because now the resulting `df.dtypes` shows the columns have a type of `object`, not `float`.