# How to import a dataframe with more than 6 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import a text file (forward_extensive.par) that has 12 significant figures but when I use pd.read_csv it only imports 6.

I have tried searching for this question online but I can't fins any reference to changing the precision in pd.

```
par_path = os.path.join(path, forward_extensive.par)                                 # define path to parameter realisation file
par = pd.read_csv(par_path, sep=r"\s*",index_col=False, header=None, skiprows=1)
```

I want values to 12 decimal places instead of 6.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check parameter [`float_precision='round_trip'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909497) ?

Comment: I tried  pd.option_context('display.precision',12) but nothing changed.  I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You data is imported with all decimals till float point.
To print them use options.display:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.16f}'.format
print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

This page mentions *display.precision* option, but for some reason
code samples use only *precision* name, e.g.:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 7)
```

So try `pd.set_option('precision', 12)`.

Another suggestion: Upgrade your *Python* installation, e.g. to *3.7* version.