# pandas load data with data type issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is the code, output and raw csv file data, the dtypes are all object type from output, is there a way to recognize each column as string (and last column as float type)? Using Python 2.7 with miniconda.

Code,

```
import pandas as pd
sample=pd.read_csv('123.csv', sep=',',header=None)
print sample.dtypes
```

program output,

```
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
```

123.csv content,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,pandas,1.2
```

**Edit 1**,

```
sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
    dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:str})
print sample.dtypes

0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object
```

**Edit 2**,

```
sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
    dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:str})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('float32')
print sample.dtypes

c_a     object
c_b     object
c_c     object
c_d    float32
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying dtype with pandas.read\_csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210962/specifying-dtype-with-pandas-read-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the argument `dtype`. And since you do not want the header, you must skip it with `skiprows` because the third element is not a float.

```
df = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
            dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
```

The output is:

```
       0       1       2    3
0  hello  python  pandas  1.2
```

**EDIT:**

To add a header with different types to your DataFrame, you can use:

```
df.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_d', 4.])
```

and the output is:

```
     c_a     c_b     c_d  4.0
0  hello  python  pandas  1.2
```

Comment: Thanks gabra, vote up, is there a way to specify data column name to be the same as header column name? In my example, I want to use `c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d` as 4 column names in pandas.

Comment: But then your fourth column header `c_d` need to be a float, which is not. You would have to change it. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to me, could you show me the solution?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks gabra, vote up. So, it seems I can either use header name, or load as specific data type but without using header name directly -- but cannot achieve both goals? :)

Comment: I am sorry, but what did you mean? This way you can get the fourth column and the fourth item in the header as float and all the others as string.

Comment: Sorry gabra, I mean there is no way I can name 4th column as its header name `c_d` as keep float type?

Comment: Oh, Ok. No, you can't have `c_d` as a float. But you can have `4.0` as a float or a string.

Comment: Thanks gabra for the clarification, vote up. See my updated post with Edit 1 section, looks like your code does not work for me, the data types are still object other than str. I am using Python 2.7 in miniconda environment, btw.

Comment: There is no problem. They are still considered as string. Take a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/2029132

Comment: Thanks gabra, I tried to convert type to float32 explicitly, and it seem it works? See my edit 2, is that code correct?

Comment: Yes. But the `c_d` in your header is still a string and not a float. To check, type `df.columns`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help gabra, mark your reply as answer. Have a good weekend. :)